# Spacy Entity Linker with Transformer Listener problem

Tags: nlp, spacy-3, spacy-transformers

I have a pretrained pipeline composed by a transformer and NER components and I am trying to create an Entity Linker able to use embedding representation produced by the transformer rather than using a CNN.
I am adding the Linker as

```py
    entity_linker = nlp.add_pipe("entity_linker",config = {
    "labels_discard": [],
    "n_sents": 0,
    "incl_prior": True,
    "incl_context": True,
    "model": {
    "@architectures": "spacy.EntityLinker.v2",
    "tok2vec": {
    "@architectures" : "spacy-transformers.TransformerListener.v1",
    "pooling" : {"@layers":"reduce_mean.v1"},
    "upstream" : "*"
    },
    "nO": 768
    },
    "entity_vector_length": 768,
    "get_candidates": {'@misc': 'spacy.CandidateGenerator.v1'},
    "threshold": None,
    })
```

but I receive dimension unset Error

```py
File "/home/blanco/wiki_kb/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spacy_transformers/layers/listener.py", line 64, in forward
width = model.get_dim("nO")
File "/home/blanco/wiki_kb/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/thinc/model.py", line 175, in get_dim
raise ValueError(err)ValueError: Cannot get dimension 'nO' for model 'transformer-listener': value unset
```

Looking online I found that this last problem typically occurs when you try to finetune a late component in the pipeline while freezing the transformer but in my case I am no quite close to that point.
My final aim would be to have a Linker that uses transformer embedding for entity and context and (maybe learning a linear layer for reprojection to a lowest dimension or in case no train at all) compares embedding coming from a knowledge base whose embedding representations have been created using the same pretrained pipeline.

Thanks in advance to everybody who will reply and help me

Current Environment

- Python 3.9.13
- spacy 3.4.4
- spacy-alignments 0.9.0
- spacy-legacy 3.0.12
- spacy-loggers 1.0.4

Comment: See: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/12329